# Call function of inner class

Tags: python, class

I have two Classes - `AClass` and `BClass`. `AClass` calls `BClass`. Now `BClass` wants to access a function defined in `AClass`. How to do it? The code below works. However, I don't know if it is Pythonic or not.

```
class AClass():

    def __init__(self):
        print("AClass init")
        pass

    def foo(self):
        print("foo")
        # Calls BClass()
        a = BClass(self)
    
    def bar(self):
        print("bar")

class BClass():
    def __init__(self, Parent):
    
        print("BClass init")
        self.Parent = Parent
        self.baz()

    def baz(self):
        # Want to call bar() function of AClass()
        self.Parent.bar()

a = AClass()
a.foo()
```

Comment: How do you mean "Pythonic"? Does it work the way you want it to? Note: You should use the inheritance if you want a proper "parent" class

Comment: Do you want to inherit the method? `class BClass(AClass):`?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: It depends on if you want to start from the child or have the parent create the child.  If the parent is creating the child, I'd say your way is the best way to do it.  If you want to create the children from your main code and give it a pre-created parent, I'd use the inherit method that @Boris is using.

Comment: The parent is creating the child. I am not trying to sub-class it like this: `class BClass(AClass):`.

Comment: This is not a python thing, this is an OO design thing.

Comment: @balderman: The code above gives me the result I want. I just wanted to know if it's the correct way to do it or not.

Comment: This seems like a waste to create an instance of a class whose only function is to call back to the original class. Why doesn’t A.foo() just A.bar() itself.

Comment: @ASarkar OK. There is no problem with what you are doing. You have a class that has a member which is another class. You want to call a "public" method of the other class. That is fine.

Comment: @quamrana: The above is just a minimal working example. In the actual code `BClass` does a lot of other things too.

Comment: Ok then. If BClass has its own cohesive behaviour, then that’s all it needs to justify its own existence.

Comment: Can you explain what is your actual problem??? Your code works as per your need. Then I couldn't find any queries on your side

Answer (score 0):

**Inheritance** is used to indicate that one `class` (child) will get most or all of its features (methods and attributes) from a `parent class`.
It allows us to define a `class` that inherits all the methods and properties from another class.

`Parent class`: the class being inherited from. `Child class` : the class that inherits from another class.

You can access the methods and variables of the parent class by using the `super() method`.
This can be achieved by:

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=0
    def method1(self):
        return self.a
class Second(First):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    #this will call the __init__() method of class First
```

This is how inheritance can be used to allow reusability of a code.
Here `First` is the `parent class` and `Second` is the `child class` whose parent is `First`.

Hope this was helpful!